# Query not updateable

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures, vba

I am trying to update local Access 2007 table with records from BE SQL Server 2012 Express.
My steps here:

1. In SQL Server exists Stored Procedure with 4 parameters to get needed records;
2. In Access VBA there is function to call SP and make temporary query:

> ```
> Public Function UpdateLocalSQLTable(strTable As String, strSQL As
> String, strSQL1 As String) As Boolean 
> On Error GoTo Err_Handler
>     Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
>     Dim strQuery As String
>     Dim conConnectString As String
>
> strQuery = "qryTemp"
> DoCmd.Close acTable, strTable
>
> If IsQueryExists(strQuery) Then DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, strQuery
>
> conConnectString = GetUserParams(NetConnDat)
>
> Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(strQuery)
> With qdf
>     .Connect = conConnectString
>     .SQL = strSQL
>     .Close 
> End With
>
> CurrentDb.Execute strSQL1
> UpdateLocalSQLTable = True
>
> qdf.Close
>
> Exit_Handler:
>     Set qdf = Nothing
>     Exit Function 
> Err_Handler:
>     Call LogError(Err.Number, Err.Description, "UpdateLocalSQLTable", , True)
>     Resume Exit_Handler 
> End Function
> ```

Here are two SQL strings passed to subroutine:

> ```
> strSQL=EXEC [dbo].[usp_TabelMakeTmpTable] @strEmp='0033111',@strMon='2014.12',@strDep='STR',@strPam='STR3'
>
> strSQL1=UPDATE tbl_tmp_Tab_s INNER JOIN qryTemp ON tbl_tmp_Tab_s.EmplCodeID0 = qryTemp.EmplCodeID0 SET tbl_tmp_Tab_s.GraphHrs = [qryTemp]![GraphHrs];
> ```

I get query "qryTemp" created well but on UPDATE statement I get error 3073. "Operation must use updateable query".

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Since the pass-through query is read-only, Access treats an `UPDATE` which joins that pass-through as read-only, too.

Comment: But I do not update pass-through query. I just use data from pass-through to update local access table.

Comment: I understand.  This is an unfortunate Access limitation.  It doesn't matter that your `UPDATE` does not attempt to change values in *qryTemp*.  Access will complain the `UPDATE` is not updateable.

Comment: Maybe there is other solution to achieve needed? I know I can create temp table from temp query and then do update from temp table but it sounds a bit dirty...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access always treats an `UPDATE` which includes a joined pass-through query as read-only.  And that holds true even when the `UPDATE` does not attempt to alter values in the pass-through.

As you mentioned in a comment, you could store the pass-through result set in an Access table.  Joining that table in place of the pass-through in the `UPDATE` should work.  However, you also mentioned that seems a bit dirty.  No argument there.  :-)

So perhaps you would prefer to use `DLookup` to fetch *qryTemp.GraphHrs* values for the `UPDATE`. This one should work, but I don't know whether the execution speed will be acceptable ...

```sql
UPDATE tbl_tmp_Tab_s
SET tbl_tmp_Tab_s.GraphHrs =
    DLookup(
        "GraphHrs",
        "qryTemp",
        "EmplCodeID0=" & EmplCodeID0
        );
```

If the datatype of *EmplCodeID0* is text rather than numeric, include quotes around its value ...

```sql
        "EmplCodeID0='" & EmplCodeID0 & "'"
```

Comment: Your approach is really good. But since I need 30 fields to update (in example one field is just for simplicity) I used another way involving two recordsets: source "qryTemp" and destination  "tbl_tmp_Tab_s". Just curious wich way would show better performance while updating 30 fields?

Comment: I suspect evaluating 30 `DLookup` expressions for each updated row would be an excessive burden on the db engine.  So if what you have now performs satisfactorily, forget about `DLookup`.   That's my best guess.  :-)