# Use query to update table by RunSQL UPDATE

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

My system is designed by Access 2013.  I setup a query to get data from SQL Server 2014 by ODBC connection.  The connection does not have problem.  I can open query1 to see all records.  Query1 is complicated and join couple tables together.   I want to use the query records to update local table.  The error message is:

Run-time error '3073'

Operation must use updateable query.

```
str = "UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN query1 AS A ON Table1.Item = A.Item SET Table1.Qty = A.Qty"

DoCmd.RunSQL str
```

Comment: UPDATE is OK, if I join two tables.  Error message comes out when I use query on the join.

Comment: Is update statement in the str working fine in Sql server management studio directly?

Comment: Update will update local table, not SQL Server table.  I cannot test it on SQL Server Management.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. *Access always treats an UPDATE which includes a joined pass-through query as read-only. And that holds true even when the UPDATE does not attempt to alter values in the pass-through.* Insert query1 into a temp table and use this for the join in the update query. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082680/query-not-updateable and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789709/operation-must-use-an-updateable-query-error-in-ms-access